# How do I draw or fill a trapezoid in java?

Tags: java, user-interface

So, you know how there are certain ways you can create shapes in Java, right? For example, there's fillRect() and drawRect(). Is there any way I can do the same thing but for a trapezoid? Like, fillTrap or drawTrap? I'm a grade 12 comp sci student, but I'm not that experienced with Java in particular.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `drawTrap` or `fillTrap` method, but there is :

```
drawPolygon(int[] x, int[] y, int numberofpoints)
```

So now using a pen and paper, you can define some points for a polygon and substitute them into the method I gave you.

Comment: I apologize but, could you give an example for a trapezoid? Since a trapezoid has 4 points, which point would be the x and y values?

Comment: its also showing an error. I did drawPolygon(50,50,4);, just to see what it would look like but it shows an error.

Comment: Look closely at the method signature, it takes 2 arrays and a number